# Why do Exceptions only sometimes demand to be surrounded in try/catch?

Tags: java, exception

I have a static Factory class that throws an exception if not `init`ed before a call is made. What I don't understand why eclipse is yelling at me for throwing the exception (it demands that I surround the toss in a try/catch) in the Factory, but in another class where I throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`, eclipse is just fine.

Is there a rule I am unaware of that I'm violating?

My static call (source of the issue):

```
public static Object createObject() {
    if (CONTEXT == null)
        throw new InstantiationException("Factory not inited.");
    // ...
}
```

Edit: I realise this would probably be better suited as a singleton instead of a static class, but the question still stands.

Comment: If you're not passing the exception back to your callers, why are you throwing it in the first place?

Comment: @CPerkins To force the break. If I don't throw this exception, a NPE will be thrown a few lines later. I'm guising the NPE as an InstantiationException to clarify what went wrong.

Comment: So you're using it basically as a goto, to avoid entering the code below which requires CONTEXT to be non-null?  It's a taste question, I suppose, but exceptions are "supposed" to be used for exceptional cases, as signals.  Instead of a throw, why not just log the error and return null (or whatever you're going to be doing in your handler)?

Comment: Nothing is really holding me back from doing that, I s'pose. Doing it your way certainly allows for more flexibility later on. (ie. A program that doesn't break)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to look at the difference between Checked exceptions and Unchecked exceptions.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

If the exception you throw is derived from RuntimeException, it is Unchecked and doesn't need to be declared/handled explicitly. All others must be.

Comment: Basically correct.  I found the article to be unclear about what happens with respect to Throwables that neither extend Error nor Exception.  So I tried it out, you can throw these kinds of Throwables, but they are checked.

Comment: The only exception (pun intended!) to the rule is RuntimeExceptions. Everything else is a checked exception. Though, if you are coding around Throwable you're most probably making a mistake.

Comment: @rleak Errors are also exceptions to the checked exception rule :) but not to the suggestion if you are throwing Errors you are probably making a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`UnsupportedOperationException` is unchecked however `InstantiationException` is checked. The difference is that one extends `Exception` and the other `RuntimeException`, which is the difference between [checked and unchecked exceptions](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129).

Answer (score 1):

You should add a throws clause to the method header:

```
public static Object createObject() throws InstantiationException
```

On `RuntimeException`, Java doc says

> A method is not required to declare in its throws clause

that is why eclipse does not scream out when it does not see it in the method declaration.

Comment: I could (and should) but not every caller to the Factory class has the necessary objects to instantiate the Factory.